# How to redirect an unauthorized user to the 403 page

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2, acl, zfc-rbac

I am using ZendFramework2 with zfc-user and `ZfcRbac` for authorization and access control. I have setup everything to work with database managed role. Now when a user navigate to an un-authorized page, I am getting the error page `You are not authorized to access this resource` which is thrown by `ZfcRbac`

Actually I have configured in my `zfc-rbac.global.php` to redirect to the 403 page. my settings are below.

```
ZfcRbac\Exception\UnauthorizedException
```

--

```
'unauthorized_strategy' => [
     'template' => 'error/403'
],
```

How do I send the user to 403 page?

**EDIT**

The right answer is to attach the `UnauthorizedStrategy` in the onBootstrap

```
$t = $e->getTarget();
$t->getEventManager()->attach(
    $t->getServiceManager()->get('\ZfcRbac\View\Strategy\UnauthorizedStrategy')
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**ZfcRbac** per default doesn't do anything but throw the exception. The power of ZfcRbac then lies within it's many, many customizable features. The one you should be looking at is found under the [Documentation-Section **"Strategies"**](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/zfc-rbac/blob/master/docs/05.%20Strategies.md#redirectstrategy).

In short

- register the redirection strategy on your Modules `onBootstrap`
- if required, change the redirection strategies configuration

Comment: Ok. thinks going well. I updated my question with correct event attachment.

Comment: the 403 page is displayed as any content. How to display a whole different layout in case of 403 error?